# How do I install Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Visual Studio 2012?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-to-install-visual-studio-2012)

How do you install Visual Studio 2010 Professional on Ubuntu 11.10?