# Can I install Microsoft Visual Studio on Ubuntu?

Tags: arm, ubuntu-minimal

I want to use OpenCV for that i need visual studio on my Ubuntu machine. is it possible to implement canny edge detection algorithm using OpenCV on ARM9? Is their any way to sort out my problem.

Comment: Nope, as far as [Visual Studio 2012](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26354) goes. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV for help on installing OpenCV on Ubuntu.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-can-i-install-visual-studio

Answer (score 4):

Check for **Monodevelop**, it is one of the alternative and most compatible IDE for visual studio, a dotnet development IDE.

http://monodevelop.com/

It is available in ubuntu repositories, just run `sudo apt-get install monodevelop`

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can run MSVS under Linux is by running it in a Virtual Machine that runs Windows. So far, there has been no success in running it under Linux, Wine, PlayOnLinux and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to program in dotnet, I second the MonoDevelop option suggested by the user above. Also, the version in the software center may not be the latest one. To get the latest version of Mono and MonoDevelop, please visit this ppa page: https://launchpad.net/~ermshiperete/+archive/monodevelop?field.series_filter=trusty