# How to install Visual Studio 2013

Tags: 14.04, dotnet

I am working on web development since a long time and I love to see visual studio in Ubuntu.

I will use it as html editor and html5 web development. It has also a great php development extension.

Have anyone find a way to install it on Ubuntu - I hope

Comment: It may work best as an application running in a VM machine with a Windows client

Comment: I know this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-can-i-install-visual-studio is not really solved. But it had been long time ago. Maybe we can find a solution

Comment: A little while ago I saw similar question, and someone said you could install Visual Studio in WINE, but it's highly unstable. Virtual Machine is the best solution available so far