# I want to install a visual basic 6 in Ubuntu 14 step by step

Tags: 14.04

We have developed an application in Visual Basic 6 as a front end. This application requires to capture automation values from machinery to system. 
It captures the data using serial port.

So here I would like to know first, will Ubuntu supports installing vb6 in it?

If that's the case, what is the process to install and execute an application that need to be installed on Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried WINE? Your question is probably answered here http://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-can-i-install-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

You can install Visual Basic 6 with `wine`. For installing `wine` you just have to deploy the setup as you do in Windows and install. Then you can find the software in `/home/.wine/drive_c/Program Files` folder. You can check [this link](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=94) to get more information of wine.