# Using in-house programs in C++ with a DLL library in Ubuntu

Tags: wine, programming, c++

I have a number of in-house programs coded in C++ using microsoft visual studio and a microsoft .dll librairy. I'm serching for a way to use those programs in Ubuntu without having to change all the classes associated with the .dll library. I would like to know if a equivalent library to the microsoft .dll library exist for Ubuntu that would allow thoses programs to be compiled in Ubuntu, or if there is a way to install those programs on Ubuntu.I have been reading about WINE, bu ti don't know if WINE is adapted to in-house programs.

Thank you

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-can-i-install-visual-studio  What happens when you try?

Answer (score 0):

*Wine* is a general solution for running Windows programs. If you have the *DLL* files installed in the appropriate location along with the program in question.

If you wish to build an application natively for Ubuntu, that was written using Windows controls from third party vendors, you would need to port your application to a portable toolkit framework such as Qt, and use the widgets provided within it, or using third party control widgets written for that toolkit, which can be used on Ubuntu (some proprietary ones may not be for example). You would also need to port any code using standard Windows controls over to the portable toolkit, and avoid using platform-specific calls. Alternatively (and possibly easier), you could write a new portable application based on these portable technologies, which is used for the same tasks, that would work on both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will start looking into Qt. One of the problems i have is time. It is not possible to go through all the applications a rewrite the calls to the dll library.