# visual studio installation on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

i want to install visual studio in Ubuntu 14.04. Moreover, i want to write and compile c++ as well as run C++ by using visual studio. is it possible in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Visual Studio?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-can-i-install-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine not, Visual Studio uses a lot of the windows specific functions. You could try [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) but I am not sure how much luck you'd have with this. If you want to use C++ though there are plenty of IDE's you could use on Linux, I personally use Eclipse which has support for C++, might want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest way to do it, is to run a Windows virtual machine on the Ubuntu host using VirtualBox or VMware. I personally use Eclipse or Qt Creator to edit the code. On Linux machines, the compilation process is a bit trickier, and most people use the terminal console to do it. Here's a quick [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJ5ADer7BfI) to help you get to know the ropes.

You should open the terminal, either by searching the apps or by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + T`.

Then type:

```
sudo apt-get update # This will update the list of programs you can download
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install g++
```

There are plenty of such tutorials in the Internet.